# How to SUM value row in javascript

Tags: javascript, sum, row

I have table like this :

```
+================================+==================+===========+=======+
+                                + the amount of fruit that has +       +
+            Fruits              +==================+===========+ Total +
+                                +        John      +   Alexa   +       +
+================================+==================+===========+=======+
+             Apple              +          5       +     3     +   8   +
+================================+==================+===========+=======+
+             Grape              +          15      +     10    +   25  +
+================================+==================+===========+=======+
+          Total Fruits          +          20      +     13    +   33  +
+================================+==================+===========+=======+
```

In Javascript how to `SUM` table in row value `(SUM in Total Fruits from sum the john apple and grape)`?

***If my explanation is incomprehensible, I apologize, and you can ask me again, Thank You***

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. Post HTML, Not line drawings

Comment: ok thanks for your advice, and sorry, I really got stuck for today